# UISearchbar text disappears when deactivating searchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a view with a search bar and search display controller. when a user enters the view the search display controller becomes active and the user can search. However, when the searchdisplay controller becomes deacivated ([self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES]) then the text disappears from the search bar

I have the searchbar linked to the view controller as _searchBar.

I've tried putting _searchBar.text = self.searchDisplayController.text in multiple places but all of them seem to still end up with the searchbar being cleared out.

Any suggestions on how I could get the text in the searchbar to stay instead of disappearing?